# PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given Warning

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Im having a little issue with PDO.
I posted another question about 2 minutes ago an that was answered pretty quickly but now I have another error.

Here is the code:

```
                $hostname='localhost';
        $username='Elmad2';
        $password='*******';
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=portals",$username,$password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM docenten');
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->execute();
            $Result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Line 81 >>      if ($dbh->query($stmt)) {

```
                foreach ($Result as $row) {


                    echo '<div class="item"><a href="teachers/item.php?id=' . $row[id] . '">
        <h1 class="title">' . $row[title]. '</h1></a>
        <h3 class="author">Geplaatst door: ' . $row[info_bys] . '</h3><span class="description">' . $row[info_shorts] . '</span><br><img src="../' . $row[filepath] . '" class="item-image"><br>
        <a href="teachers/item.php?id='.$row[id].'"><button type="button" class="read_more btn btn-primary">Lees meer</button></a>
    </div>';



                }
            }
            else{
                echo 'error';
            }

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And here is the error:

> Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in >/home/ubuntu/workspace/portals/teachers.php on line 81

I hope someone can help me,

Thanks.

Comment: You already executed and fetched the data, what do you want to do with that query call there?!

Comment: So I need to remove line 81?

Comment: Yes, the entire if-else statement.

Comment: okay let me try that

Comment: Also don't forget your quotes when you access the data, e.g. `$row[xy]` should be `$row["xy"]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `PDO::query()`. For a prepared statement, you call `PDO::prepare()`, then `PDOStatement::execute()` performs the query and you can retrieve the result using `PDOStatement::fetch*`.

`PDO::query()` is only used for dynamic SQL; it takes as its argument the *string* SQL query statement eg. **`SELECT`** statement, &c.

Answer (score 0):

@rizier123 answered my question.

I just needed to delete the if statement and add quotes to the row data.

Thanks @rizier123